# doubts about finding an equation of a projective plane

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let a,b,c point of projective space  $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$  of homogeneus coordinates $a=[1,A]$ $b=[1,B]$ $c=[1,C]$ find cartesian equation of projective plane containing $a$, $b$ and $c$. This is the original test but i have some doubts , isn't $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$? I think this problem is impossible but I could be wrong. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$, but you can imagine $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$ as $\mathbb R^4$, where all points on a line through the origin are glued together, i.e. we identify two points $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ in $\mathbb R^4$, if there is a $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ with  $y=\lambda x$.

What do you think about
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & x & y & z\\1&a_1&a_2&a_3\\
1&b_1&b_2&b_3\\
1&c_1&c_2&c_3\end{bmatrix}=0?
$$

Comment: thanks for answering  your idea is correct but applied to my problem I have homogeneus coordinates , so this means that I "have to add another parameter" but in this case i will have points of 3 coordinates that is not like $\mathbb R^4$ this was my doubts having only 2 original coordinates for a,b and c

Comment: Hello :) $(1,x,y,z)$ are homogeneus coordinates :) But you can replace it by $(2,2x,2y,2z)$ or $(-1,-x,-y,-z)$ or $(u_0,u_1,u_2,u_3)$. The first coordinate means that we intersect our lines through the origin at the (3-dimensional) hyperplane $x_0=1$, but you can choose it whatever you want.

Comment: Hi sorry again and thanks for your patience the fact is that I have as homogeneus coordinates only $(1 , a_1)$ for all 3 points, so i am missing the other 2 coordinates. Should i write something like  $\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & x & y & z\\1& A &a_2&a_3\\
1& B &b_2&b_3\\
1& C &c_2&c_3\end{bmatrix}=0?$
 with $a_2 ,a_3 ,b_2,b_3,c_2,c_3$  as parameters?

Comment: i suppose, that $A$, $B$ and $C$ have three components, they are elements of $\mathbb R^3$. Maybe i am wrong, but otherwise, it makes no sense. There are three points given, maybe $a=[1,2,3,4]$, $b=[1,4,3,2]$ and $c=[1,3,2,4]$. And you have to check, if a point $[u_0,u_1,u_2,u_3]$ is in the hyperplane, spanned by that vectors, right?

Comment: yeah that's why originally I thought the problem was not solvable really thanks for your patience and your explanation

Comment: You're welcome :D